# Word to describe being apprehensive about the possibility of something you’re excited about NOT happening?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there a word to describe the emotional state of being simultaneously excited about the prospect of something and dreading the prospect of it not happening? The closest thing I can think of is "disappointment" but I don't think that covers a future tense hypothetical.

The use of the word would be something like:

> "I am excited because I think they're going to offer me the job but I'm worried that they won't."

Would transform to:

> I am *(word or phrase)* about the job offer.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Can you provide an example sentence of how you may use the word? Also, what research have you done to find the word? Have any words come close? If so, why were they not a good fit? Please provide more information.

Comment: The number of different words that can be used to describe the emotions involved makes it difficult to actually do any sort of keyword search. I actually don't have a lot of hope that there is a phrase, let alone a single-word, that covers this in English but I figured I'd ask.

I've added some clarification, including an example, though.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283046/what-is-one-word-for-the-nervous-excitement-associated-with-new-things

Comment: @Hank Looking over that I would say I'm looking for a word or phrase that describes anticipating two things that are opposite. "Anxious anticipation" is pretty close, actually.

Comment: The **Butterflies** answer seemed to cover both sensations.

Comment: Anxious can mean yeah, yeah and oh, no.

Comment: The word "ambivalence" comes to mind, and it would be perfect if it meant simply that you have two primary emotions in your mind at the same time. It does not mean that, however. Ambivalence is associated with two CONFLICTING emotions which are battling in your psyche at the same time. I doubt there is a single word to express what you are after. "Mixed emotions" could work, but again, when we think of mixed emotions we (I) think of conflicting emotions which pull us in opposite directions (e.g., yes or no, red or green, buy or not to buy, love or not love, anticipation or dread).

Comment: I edited your title. Your to you're (you are).

Answer (score 7):

You are ***on tenterhooks*** about the job offer.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/199236?redirectedFrom=on%20tenterhooks#eid18931860)

> to be on (the) tenterhooks: i.e. in a state of painful suspense or impatience:

[Worldwidewords.org](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-ont1.htm) explains further

> It comes from one of the processes of making woollen cloth. After it
>   had been woven, the cloth still contained oil from the fleece, mixed
>   with dirt. It was cleaned in a fulling mill, but then it had to be
>   dried carefully or it would shrink and crease. So the lengths of wet
>   cloth were stretched on wooden frames, and left out in the open for
>   some time. This allowed them to dry and straightened their weave.
>   These frames were the tenters, and the tenter hooks were the metal
>   hooks used to fix the cloth to the frame. At one time, it would have
>   been common in manufacturing areas to see fields full of these frames
>   (older English maps sometimes marked an area as a tenter-field). So it
>   was not a huge leap of the imagination to think of somebody on
>   tenterhooks as being in an state of anxious suspense, stretched like
>   the cloth on the tenter.

Comment: Excellent word choice! Don

Answer (score 1):

You are ***anxious*** about the job offer.

Anxious:

> wanting something very much, typically with a feeling of unease.

[Explanation/definition for anxious](https://www.google.com/search?q=anxious%20definition&oq=anxious&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3593j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: As demonstrated in the example, anxious denotes either anticipation or avoidance but does not adequately do so at the same time.

Comment: How does *wanting something very much, typically with a feeling of unease* include anything like *fearing something, much or slightly*?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Apparently from all the messages I'm getting from senior members we should not be answering questions like these anyway. I still fail to see how comments help clean up the site versus "answers". There is still no clear line on what we should answer. Sigh.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Did someone say "fearing". I didn't see it. They said worried in the question post. It still says it now (?). wanting something very much + unease. Unease = a type of worry. But again it's not the kind of question they want us answering anyway. Apparently this guy/girl should have done his own homework instead of asking for help here? I'm at a loss about some of this. Sigh. Seems I'm getting these comments/msgs about answers we shouldn't be "answering" but rather "commenting on(?!) Oy!

Comment: Uh… Please, what messages are you getting?

Apart from anything else very loosely, an Answer might be *Black and white are not the same at all* while a comment might be *Are you sure this about black and white? Is there no room for grey?*

Either way, how is any kind of *cleaning* relevant, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin No, no, not msgs from you. From some senior members/mods. Apparently these questions are not to be answered. That was my point. I'm just getting ticked off b/c I'm getting flack for answering questions instead of posting comments (which they seem to prefer). Are you a native speaker btw? Maybe I'm not being clear. I don't mean to offend. Just asking.

Comment: @ Kace36 No-one said *fearing* nor should they have needed to. Your search engine will tell you *fearing* and *dreading* are almost perfectly synonymous.

Who, please, said it's not the kind of question they want answering?

If you’re not sure about the difference between Answers and Comments, use Comments… when appropriate, people will suggest you make your Comment an Answer.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I think we are getting totally confused. Haha. You said "fearing" Robbie. You said it. Above. Second comment. My talks about the commenting/answering is just b/c I've gotten msgs about only answering certain types of questions. Just forget it.

Comment: @Kace36 Yes, I said *fearing*. I said that. I said it above. How is that confusing, please?

I understand you've gotten messages about only answering certain types of questions and for at least the third time, what messages have you got and how do they relate to this question?

Why is any of this difficult, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I'm saying let's drop it b/c I don't really care about this question. I was venting. I'm not sure you are understanding. My venting about the situation was separate from this issue of the answer. If you want to know about the answer please read my first comment. Anxious is the correct word. It's a feeling of excitement + a feeling of unease. Unease is a type of dread, fear, loathing, etc. It fits what the poster was asking about. The messages don't matter. They are from mods and just talking about how we should not answer simple dictionary questions. Okay?

Comment: If you really want to cop out after wasting so much time I can't stop you, and if you can find one or two people who think that's OK, do please name them.

Next time you don't care about something, how about ignoring it? Please? Pretty please?

Comment: I'm not copping out of anything. I think there is confusion and I was not aware that English doesn't seem to be your first language. I do not mean that as an offensive thing I just feel we are wasting time b/c you don't seem to be understanding what I'm saying. That's all. I'm not being disrespectful, not trying to waste your time, nothing. I just felt we were getting nowhere. I explained why Anxious is correct. I already did that. What more could you want? @RobbieGoodwin

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin If you truly want to know more about the word **anxious** then look online. However I posted the exact meaning. The OP asked for something that means excited but also dreading something or worrying at the same time. Anxious = excited + feeling of unease. Unease is a type of dread, loathing, worry, etc. Now having said that maybe he didn't word his question properly. But that **is** what anxious means. There are surely other words too.