# What's the word for "anxious in a good way"

Tags: synonyms

Like anxious but not anxious. The good version of anxious. Anxious but not bad. Anxious but I don't feel horrible

Comment: It might help if you give an actual example. In what situation would this good anxiety (excitement?) occur?

Comment: Do you mean, like, *eager*?

Comment: Consider *excited* (emotionally aroused) or *keyed up* (very excited or nervous, usually before an important event) ?

Comment: Nervous excitement / nervously excited / full of nervous/excited anticipation …

Comment: This really a [single word request](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and should be tagged so. However, it lacks the required description of how the desired word would be used.

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is anticipation. It was part of this thread
[What is one word for "the nervous excitement associated with new things"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283046/what-is-one-word-for-the-nervous-excitement-associated-with-new-things)